# AIR Highlight search results inside image

Tags: image, search, air, highlight

We have an Adobe AIR application. It has an image preview feature to show TIF and JPG images inside a TitleWindow.
My requirement is as follows:
i want to highlight(yellow color) a line containing a searched term results inside that image.
i found out examples which can highlight text inside a textarea. But wanted the same thing inside image.
There can be multiple lines having this keyword. All those llines have to be highlighted.
Not sure if this is possible. Please let me know how can this be done in Flex/AIR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create mx.controls.Text, assign style which will paint it yellow and place over the Image. This can be done, for example, with Canvas container which allows absolute positioning.
mx:Text has no background, so it will just text over image. Or do you need some background as well?